# Autopost is not working

Tags: social-network

I want to autopost the contents in facebook.I installed [Drupal for Facebook](https://www.drupal.org/project/fb) module and created Apps in facebook.

In this,the user can connect facebook.But the content doesn't get autopost.
I got an error like this

"Something went wrong while posting update to your facebook wall. The error has been captured by watchdog".

How to clear this error.
[image]

Comment: Do you have the dblog module switched on? If so, please post the watchdog error. Seems like your oauth authentication isn't going through.

Comment: "Post to facebook options not available. Possibly a temporary failure to reach facebook.com, or an expired access token."

Comment: "Failed to access facebook altering node-form.: fb_graph failed querying . OAuthException: Error validating application. Application has been deleted."@olyN I got this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error says your application has been deleted. Go to https://developers.facebook.com and check your application under the "Apps" tab. If the app exists, check that your oauth details (on the drupal site) match. If the app doesn't exist, create an app (also under the "Apps" tab) and validate against that in your Drupal site's oauth settings.

Comment: My facebook app exists, I gave the same app id and secret key in facebook oauth settings.Still It shows the same error.